# How can I extend django-admin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates, django-admin

I have been looking for a way to extend the default django admin so that it can be showing User KPI's like **Total Users** any suggestions?

Instead would it be proper to just create a separate view for that without tampering the default admin

Answer (score 0):

actually if you want to add anything in the already generated admin panel you can easily do that on admin.py

all you need to do is you have to extend class admin.modeladmin and create class and register that with your model register

there is a whole documentation related to change the model admin field
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/